# A div, independent from the other, in the middle left of the whole body, whose height becomes

Tags: html, css

Basically I have two divs in the body. One main div, and one that's the one I want independently in the horizontal left and vertical middle of the whole page, and I want its height to be big as the whole page's on hover. I tried using absolute position, which should work, but it doesn't, so here I am asking. The div element that I want independent and in teh middle left is "search" div. Here's the whole code and a picture I uploaded to explain better what I want to achieve, just in case: http://postimg.org/image/c6x9bso21/

```css
/* CSS Document */
html {
 height:100%;
}


body {
 background-color:rgba(1,130,255,1);
 width:100%;
 min-height:100%;
}

#main {
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

#logo {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:130px;
 height:130px;
}

.logo {
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 width:130px;
 height:130px; 
}

#abovenavigation {
 margin:0 auto;
}

#container {
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 list-style:none;
 font-size:0;
}

li {
 margin:0 20px;
 font-size:18px;
 display:inline-block;
}

h1 {
 margin:0 50px;
 display: inline-block;
 color:#FFF;
 font-family:"cooper Std Black";
}


h1:hover {
 color:rgba(1,130,255,1);
 background-color:#FFF;
 border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border: 0px solid #000000;
}

.Home {
 color:rgba(1,130,255,1);
 background-color:#FFF;
 border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border: 0px solid #000000;
}

.facebook:hover {
 background-color:#FFF;
 border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border: 0px solid #000000;
}

.twitter:hover {
 background-color:#FFF;
 border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border: 0px solid #000000;
}

.mailto:hover {
 background-color:#FFF;
 border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border: 0px solid #000000;
}

#me {
 width:300px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

#search {
 position:absolute;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.search {
 background-color:#FFF;
 border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
 border: 0px solid #000000;
}

#undernavigation {
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
<link rel="icon" href="Senza titolo-1.ico" />
</head>

<body>
 
    <div id="main">
     
        <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
        <img src="LogoU.png" width="130px" height="130px" />
        </a>
        </div><!--ends logo-->
        
        <br/>
        <br/>
        
        <div id="abovenavigation">
        
        <ul id="container">
         
            <li><a href="index.html"><h1 class="Home">HOME</h1></a></li><!--
            --><li><h1 class="About">ABOUT</h1></li><!--
            --><li><h1 class="Blog">BLOG</h1></li><!--
            -->
            
        </ul><!--ends container--> 
           
        </div><!--ends upper navigation-->
        
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <div id="me">
        <img src="Gregory1.png" width="300px" height="300px" onclick="this.src='Gregory2.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Gregory2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Gregory1.png'"/>
  </div>
        
        <br/>
        <br/>
        
        <div id="undernavigation">
         
            <ul id="container">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Albus.Severus.Vitanza" target="_blank"><img class="facebook" src="Facebook.png" width="53px" height="50px" onclick="this.src='Facebookhov.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Facebookhov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Facebook.png'"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Promoetheus" target="_blank"><img class="twitter" src="Twitter.png" width="53px" height="50px" onclick="this.src='Twitterhov.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Twitterhov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Twitter.png'" /></a></li>
            <li><a href:"mailto:gaaren03@gmail.com"><img class="mailto" src="Mailto.png" width="53px" height="50px" onclick="this.src='Mailtohov.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Mailtohov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Mailto.png'" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </div><!--ends undernavigation-->
        
    </div><!--ends main-->
    
    <div id="search"> 
    <img class="search" src="Search.png" height="50px" width="50px" />
    </div>
          
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be it will work!

```
#search:hover{
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I menaged to out in the middle left. This I tried and it doesn't work, and both the parents have a height of 100%..

Answer (score 0):

I was stupid to ask this as I menaged to fix it playing with negative margins: the answer is this code I just wrote: #search {

```
text-align:left;
    margin-top:-300px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
}

#search:hover {
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin-top:-640px;
    position:absolute;
}

#search:hover img {
    display:none;
}
```